# How to store tree data structure in objc

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tree data structure with my response . 
I want to save it in memory without using core data. is thr any way to save it [image]

Currently im using a recrusive function to loop the json response

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? It says you want to 'save it in memory' and you state that you are using a recursive function to print out the JSON response. This sounds like you already have an NSDictionary to use, therefore it's already in memory. If you're interested in saving it on disk, then that's different.

Comment: Yes correct. i have it in a dictionary. but i want this data push in to my view controller .

Comment: property (assign) int categoryId;
property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *categoryName;
property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *parentName;
property (assign) int parentId;
property (assign) int position;
property (assign) int childExists;
property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;
This is my category model

Comment: If you just want to pass it to your view controller, then you can do it by passing it in a constructor or via a property. I assume the properties that you pasted above are on a model object of sorts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to deserialize it using a professional json parser, then set a property on the view controller....

```
// MyViewController.m
@interface MyViewController ()
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *webResult;
@end
```

The web response probably starts out as `NSData *data`, build NSObjects like this:

```
self.webResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```